# How to convert letters to numbers in dict

Tags: python

```
def get_phone_number(word_str):
    numpad_dict={'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 2, 'd': 3, 'e': 3, 'f': 3, 
                 'g': 4, 'h': 4, 'i': 4, 'j': 5, 'k': 5, 'l': 5, 
                 'm': 6, 'n': 6, 'o': 6, 'p': 7, 'q': 7, 'r': 7, 
                 's': 7, 't': 8, 'u': 8, 'v': 8, 'w': 9, 'x': 9, 'y': 9, 'z': 9}
    number = '0800painter'
    re_text = ''
    for digit in number:
        re_text += str(numpad_dict.get(digit, digit))
    return re_text


def test_get_phone_number():
    print(get_phone_number('0800painter'))
    print(get_phone_number('0800fixnow'))

def main():
    print("===========\nQuestion 1:")
    test_get_phone_number()
main()
```

output:

```
===========
Question 1:
08007246837
08007246837
```

I got one answer from my first def function, How to get second answer based on '0800fixnow'? Do I need to write two for loop to get the answer or just one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining the number in the `get_phone_number` function and not using the number provided in the function arguments. Changing the function to

```
def get_phone_number(word_str):
    numpad_dict={'a': 2, ..., 'z': 9} # Shortened for example
    re_text = ''
    for digit in word_str:
        re_text += str(numpad_dict.get(digit, digit))
    return re_text
```

should fix your issue.

Comment: No need to call `str`, either.

Comment: @DYZ in line 5? `re_text += str(...)`

Comment: I removed it and was getting a 'cannot add string and int variables'

Comment: Ok, sorry, you indeed use number in the dictionary (but it would be more efficient to use strings '1', '2', etc., because the digits are really never used as numbers in your example.)

Answer (score 0):

```
numpad_dict = {
  2: "abc",
  3: "def",
  4: "ghi",
  5: "jkl",
  6: "mno",
  7: "pqrs",
  8: "tuv",
  9: "wxyz"
}

def letter_to_number(phone_number):
  output = ""
  for character in phone_number:
    try:
      int(character)
      output += character
    except ValueError:
      for key in numpad_dict:
        if character in numpad_dict[key]:
          output += str(key)
          break
  return output

print(letter_to_number('0800painter'))
print(letter_to_number('0800fixnow'))

# returns

08007246837
0800349669
```